# How many beakers does Great Scientist give in Civilization V Gods & Kings?

Tags: civilization-5

When you consume a Great Scientist on research how many beakers does it produce? Is there a cap to how many technology you can unlock by bulbing Great Scientists?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's based on the science output of your civ, like it gives you "x" amount of turns worth of science. I could be wrong though, and I don't know the exact amount.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A great scientist when expended gives you the total of your last 8 turns of science output.

This includes science from city-states, bonuses, etc.

Comment: Do any beakers every get wasted? or does it rollover into other technologies?

Comment: It rolls over to the next technology you're researching

Comment: Does it include the big bonus from expired research agreements? If so, it would really pay off to start a bunch together and bulb at the end.

Comment: If the science boost is based on the total output of the empire, then would it make sense to re-assign all the specialists and workers in all the cities to get some extra science and then use the Great Scientist and then change everything back?

Comment: Science specialists are usually assigned in major cities anyway so it doesn't have much of an impact anyway. Not to say it is never useful but its a lot of work to go through for a relatively tiny improvement (minor improvement in science at the cost of whatever else